# Should this question showing a poor understanding of PHP be closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

In bygone days I would have closed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21886590/505722) using the minimal understanding reason.

No as it stands there seems to be no appropriate close reason (maybe Too Broad?).

Does this mean that this question is on topic?

Comment: Given that you answered the question, you seem to feel the question is answerable, rather than close worthy.  If you think that it's close worthy, why did you answer it?  If you think a question is answerable, but just feel that the author didn't spend sufficient time/effort working on their problem or in writing up the question, then a downvote is the appropriate way to provide that feedback.

Comment: @Servy Because Stack Overflow is intended to be a useful resource for people. Clearly this question isn't going to be much use to anyone aside from the asker. Hence I think it's closeworthy. Having said that, a lot of people participate in stack overflow to help people. Answering the question didn't take much time but hopefully helped the user.

Comment: It's simply contridictory.  Either you think that the question should be answered, in which case it should be open, or you think it shouldn't be answered, and it should be closed.  Saying, that you want to answer it, and then close it so that nobody can write a competing answer is simply dishonest and hypocritical.

Comment: @Servy Dishonest? That seems a bit strong. If I was being dishonest I'd have chosen a close vote at random and not have posted about it on meta. Perhaps I shouldn't have answered but I don't see the issue with attempting to help the OP regardless of the fate of his question.

Comment: I'm saying that if you had voted to close and answered, it would have been dishonest.  You answered and didn't vote to close, which implies that you feel the question is answerable, and that answering it is appropriate.  Which is an acceptable opinion to have.  If, however, you feel that it's not answerable, or that answering it isn't appropriate (which is what closing is specifically stating) then you shouldn't be answering it.  Either the question is answerable, or it's not.  It's not both at the same time though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The real issue with that question is not the code, but the fact that the problem the OP *claims* to be trying to solve (find a number within ±10 of a given number using binary search) is plain nonsensical.  This suggests that either:

- the OP suffers from a *really* bad case of [the X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem),
- the question is just badly written, and the problem the OP is *actually* trying to solve is something completely different, or
- the problem is a (rather contrived) homework exercise intended to teach the OP something (in which case the only way to *usefully* answer it would be to first find out *what* the OP is supposed to learn from it and then help them learn it).

In any case, it's very unlikely that any answer to that question would ever help anyone *except*, just possibly, the OP.  Thus, it *should* be closed *somehow* (and eventually deleted) to keep it from cluttering up the site.  I've just voted to close it as **"unclear what you're asking"**, and left a comment stating why I think the question, in its present form (and your attempt notwithstanding), cannot be *usefully* answered.

---

Ps. If you think that a question should be closed, you generally should *not* answer it.  This is particularly true for questions that should be closed due to low quality / lack of future value, since the presence of an upvoted or accepted answer on a closed question will make it ineligible for [automatic deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).  If you wish to provide feedback to the OP on how to improve their question, you can always use comments.

---

Pps. Note that, if you think that a question is off topic for some reason other than the pre-written ones given in the menu, [you can always use the "other" option and write in the close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216503/using-old-off-topic-close-reasons-under-other).  In particular, note that most of the "old" close reasons, including "minimal understanding", are still listed in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as categories of off-topic questions.

Comment: `the presence of an upvoted or accepted answer on a closed question will make it ineligible for automatic deletion` I'll accept that I acted wrongly in that case. I'd assumed answering was a harmless way of helping out a fellow stack overflower while the question was on it's way to deletion. If this is the case then a comment would have been more approriate.

Comment: Ah, I also didn't know that answering the question means deletion is ineligible.  thanks Ilmari

Answer (score 1):

No, in my opinion it shouldn't be  closed.

OP actually used code formatting?!? Wonderful!

OP demonstrates some reasonable effort? Super!

So I'm no expert in PHP, and I can't judge if it's a super-easy question. But to me, the fact that it looks complicating-enough tells me it's a valid question. It's *easy to you*, but not to OP.

Way better than other stuff I've seen.

Comment: You seem to have a pretty low bar for quality if you're mostly just ensuring that people formatted code as code...especially given that that code has *really awful* formatting, even after the edit.

Comment: @Servy - Hey, we've both seen some *really* low-quality stuff; so in comparison - it's pretty-OK :-)  . But true- the code indentation is definitely off ; that's sort of a persistent issue we see though

Comment: The fact that other people have made far worse questions doesn't mean that this is up to the standard that we'd like to see on this site.  SO has been successful by demanding a very high standard of quality, despite constant pushback to lower the bar.

Comment: @Servy - You have a good point. I agree, and the main issue however is the user-base.  it is a struggle I know