# With no current "Minimal Understanding" reason, what should you do with questions with no minimal understanding?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Was poking around my usual haunt, the MS-Access tag, when I came upon this disaster:

[MS Access VB forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880111/ms-access-vb-forms)

I hope I didn't come off sounding too snotty in my comment, but the guy/gal didn't even tag it properly, and it's clear he's fresh from Boot Camp.  In the old days, this was a no-brainer: Close it because even a minimal understanding of the application wasn't shown.

So, what do we do now?  Do we just downvote it?

Comment: Option 1: _.. unclear what yu are asking .._.  Option 2: _This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself._

Answer (score 10):

Can you figure out what help the user needs?

- Yes, I can, but I am irritated that the question is so cluelessly phrased.

  - Edit if you can, downvote if you want
- No, I have no proof this person can work the tool or knows a single keyword from the language or what a database even is.

  - Close as unclear what you're asking because you don't know if they are asking for code, instructions in the tool, design advice or what

Works for me.

Related: [What is a better name for Unclear What You're Asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215705/147247) in which I argue for "Unclear What Help You Need".