# Generally horrible questions

Tags: feature-request

I think we need a close reason for generally bad questions that are hard to find a close reason for. Ones that are usually getting shoehorned into "Too Broad" or "Unclear What You're Asking". Something like:

> This question shows a complete lack of understanding of the general concepts, and as such is unlikely to be answerable in its current form. A tutorial is likely in order.

and/or

> This answer is asking for code or homework help, and shows no effort at solving the problem. It is unlikely to be able to be edited to get better.

If anyone knows what the consensus is on what to do with these questions when they come up, please enlighten me.

**TL;DR:** It's too hard to choose an accurate close reason for homework / give me code / complete misunderstanding of the language/concepts as a whole questions.

Comment: tl;dr: we tried this. The end result was the closure and destruction of far too many useful, heavily-referenced "canonical" questions based on petty irritation at some long-departed asker's skill or motivation. It was a complete disaster.

Comment: @Shog9 What about the homework/code-request questions?

Comment: That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: you may be interest in my thought of changing Unclear What You're Asking to Unclear What Help You Need https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215705/what-is-a-better-name-for-unclear-what-youre-asking/215806#215806 eg we don't know if you know what a debugger is, or what you've tried, etc.