# Should users be able to downvote a moderator's action?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, moderation

It is apparent to me that the moderators aren't really moderated. I have read many articles where moderators get overzealous in their quest to have "perfect" information.

It's like some kind of cult where if you can get in and follow the creed you can do whatever you want. There's no second opinion and no way to obtain one.

A great example is a question "[Does the internet exist?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/21725/does-the-internet-exist)" It's a good question, but the moderator decides to close it saying **It's unclear what you're asking**. I know exactly what he is asking. Its very clear to me.

He wants to know, does the internet exist? If so what's the proof?

There is another post here which asks "[What recourse do I have if I believe the moderator has abused their privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-his-her-privileges)?" This is a question of the poster's perspective on the moderation. It doesn't address what the community in general things about the moderator. It also appears to be a question of escalation rather than feedback. So I think it is a different question. My question is more about a way for the entire community to give numerical feedback about a moderator's specific action. If the community likes their moderation they can know how much or how little with something like an upvote or downvote. It's a lot of work to "have recourse" on someone and that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking about a way to provide feedback about monitor activity in a non-black and white way. Meaning non-recourse needed, merely "I don't like what you did" way.

Comment: [What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused his/her privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/307988)

Comment: Moderators are certainly moderated - by the community, other moderators and community managers. What makes you believe this isn't enough and that *every single action* of a moderator should be help up to scrutiny beyond that?

Comment: The person closed that question didn't seems like a mod anymore

Comment: The closing of questions if very much determined/steered by the community. I can't judge why the mod choose to close the question, it is best asked at their meta. Beyond that you can always leave a comment (they left comments to explain comments why they closed it) to contest closure, edit the question into shape if warranted or cast a re-open vote if you have the privilege. There is no need to *down-vote* a moderator, they are just regular users with a couple of power buttons. And keep in mind we don't down vote users, we down vote posts.

Comment: see also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215705/what-is-a-better-name-for-unclear-what-youre-asking for more on what makes a question "unclear"

Comment: "It's like some kind of cult" Did you want to try to defend that on some kind of factual basis, or are you just aiming for being written off as a crackpot? "if you can get in" Right, so, moderators [are elected _by non-moderators_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360/159251). "There's no second opinion" [Simply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36415/159251), [false](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/159251).

Comment: How can we see the internet if our eyes aren't even real?

Comment: @Won't You use your mind's eye.

Comment: @Ramhound: Users with less than 3k (or less than 500 on a beta site like Philosophy) have no actions to take to reopen a question that has either been a) closed more than 5 days ago or b) resolved as Leave Closed after an edit put it in the Reopen queue. There is no flag for the purpose (and a custom mod flag is highly likely to be declined, for the good reason that mods are not there to be stalking horses for flaggers); the only possible thing to do is to raise the question on meta or in chat and hope someone else will vote to reopen.

Comment: Granted all the Moderators will be upset by my question and demand that I provide facts and articulate my arguments well. Please understand that some questions and some answers are based on perception and that GOOD answers demand an equally perception based response which might not be emotionless and completely objective.

Comment: @Nathan Mods, like stack users get points for modding. Therefore the site is encouraging some action in it and of itself when in many cases action is not need, action is taken because all action by a moderator is seen as good when in many cases it is not. A vote up and down will create accountability and thoughtfulness to the action just like the non-moderators are subjected to.

Comment: @NathanTuggy So they have no possible recourse, except for the one option that's available to them.  Since you've specifically described an action that they can take, clearly they *do* have an action they can take.

Comment: @JoshWoodcock: I wish it were true that moderation actions added to rep. In point of fact, that simply isn't so at all, in any fashion. Diamond mods don't even get *badges* for their actions.

Comment: @JoshWoodcock That last comment, like so much of your question, is simply wrong.  Mods don't get points for moderating.  They do it because they intrinsically want the site to be better.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, they can *bring it up on Meta*, which is what Ramhound was *specifically objecting to*.

Comment: @NathanTuggy You said that they have no actions to take to get a question reopened.  They do have an action they can take.  Sure, Josh may not like that action; he's more than welcome to not want to use it, but the action *does* exist; you can't just say that there is no action to take.

Comment: @Servy: No, I said *Ramhound* was objecting to the OP taking this one action (via this very question), the only action that has no direct site effect, and telling them to "vote" instead, which is not possible in any fashion. Please do read context.

Comment: @NathanTuggy If you said that Josh can't vote to reopen, as suggested, then sure, that's a perfectly correct statement.  Saying they have no actions they can take when they feel a question should be reopened is false; they *do* have actions they can take to attempt to get the question reopened.

Comment: @Ramhound: Did you mean flag a moderator to reopen? As I said earlier, this is generally strongly discouraged, since a moderator acting on private flags' reasoning has no transparency. Other than that, there are no votes, flags, or other direct site actions available for a question closed for more than 5 days, period.

Comment: @Servy: Those "actions" do not have any direct effects in the site software, so I do not consider them in the same category. Otherwise, all flagging, voting (except up- and down-voting), and so forth would just be meta discussions. This is clearly utterly unscalable and hopelessly inefficient: meta is for really exceptional cases or general discussions of trends, not "post X should have status Y removed/added" minutia, which belong in the software layer, where site privileges have direct effects of some sort.

Comment: @Nathan I didn't mean Points = Rep. I meant that moderation is seen as positive because it is moderation.

Comment: @Ramhound: I don't have any dog in the fight either. I just don't want people recommending things to newbies that are flat-out impossible, or things that will only get a terse rejection. And it's a fact that SE site software just does not support reopen flagging the way it supports close flagging. Pretending it does doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @JoshWoodcock: If you mean that most users see diamond mod actions as positive even when they aren't, I don't think adding votes to allow them to express this in a more formal way will help anything at all. I would actually expect, based on experience, that users tend to either ignore diamond mod actions almost entirely, or object to those actions mostly when those actions go against their interests. Based on this, the votes would be rather imbalanced, and not especially informative.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - My original comment was still a valid option.

Comment: @JoshWoodcock And what's your basis for that assertion?

Comment: @Ramhound are you really say that the community members aren't intelligent enough to participate? Or you're saying that community members don't participate? Or you're saying that participation from the community won't be helpful because the community members don't know what they're doing? I'm confused.

Comment: Look guys I lost 30 rep for asking a valid question. Great way to encourage collaboration guys.

Answer (score 15):

The ability to oppose the closure of a question already exists—users with the privilege to [close questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) may vote to reopen. Even when moderators vote to close, 5 users can vote to reopen, if they decide that the question was improperly closed.

I don't see any value in adding a 'downvote' mechanism for users to express disagreement with a moderation decision:

- If a question is improperly closed, trusted users on the site can vote to reopen. Once there is one reopen vote, the post will be sent to a review queue for users to decide whether to 'Leave Closed' or 'Reopen', so eventually the post will be handled by the community.
- Users who don't yet have the privilege to reopen can create a question on the [per-site meta](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/) for Philosophy, making a clear case for why the question should be reopened. You can see this in action on [The Workplace's meta site](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4526/reopen-specialist-roles-killing-my-ability-to-leave-reopened).

The vast majority of moderator actions can be reviewed and counteracted by the community—closed posts can be reopened by the community; deleted posts can be seen by high-rep users and flagged for review if necessary. Other moderation decisions, such as suspensions, are overseen by Community Managers (employees at Stack Exchange). You can be sure that almost every decision made by a moderator is open for scrutiny by at least one other party, to ensure that moderation is fair and consistent.

Note that the moderator who closed the question [left some comments](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/21725/does-the-internet-exist#comment49450_21725) explaining exactly why the question was closed:

> Your title question "Does the internet exist?" is too broad to be reasonably answered here. The question in the body of your post, "Would ... anti-realists say [the internet] exists?" is acceptable in scope, but you don't provide us any context or definitions so it remains unanswerable. 1st, define "the internet". You seem to have defined existence as something you can "smell, touch, taste, or hear" but are you sure that definition is satisfactory? Reality, conceptual existence, these are complicated issues that can easily become more confusing if you don't stop to establish a starting point.
>
> Philosophy is a tricky subject, and we don't want to discourage new users from posting questions they have, but we really do want to encourage people to think about their questions themselves before they ask, and write down what they think and what is going on in their minds, too. This way we can work through the problem rather than just guessing what your question is really about and potentially giving you an answer to the wrong question. :)

The issue here is that although you can tell *what* the question is trying to ask, there isn't sufficient information to give a proper answer on the Philosophy site.

Keep in mind that *unclear what you're asking* doesn't necessarily mean *unintelligible*, just that there isn't enough information to reasonably answer **in the question's current state**. It's also quite broad at the moment, so it could also be closed as *too broad*.

Comment: You're posing your logic from a position of pure objectivity. What I'm saying is that many questions and answers especially in philosophy are asked and answered from a subjective perspective and rightly so since there are likely many valid viewpoints. Many moderators are moderating out the subjectivity on very subjective questions even in cases where subjectivity is more appropriate than objectivity.

Comment: If you have an issue with moderation on a specific site, @JoshWoodcock , you should raise it on the specific Meta first. You cannot generalize moderator actions across every site from one question whose closure or editing you disapprove of.

Comment: It's not a moderator in a specific site. This is a problem with every Stack community.

Comment: @JoshWoodcock The general philosophy for subjective questions is outlined at [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). The discouragement of highly subjective questions comes from years of experience with Q&A, which has shown that really subjective, broad questions don't provide *useful* answers. If you see a question that does meet those criteria, but isn't being handled, you can take any of the actions I mentioned earlier (voting to reopen, meta posts). I can't speak for the Philosophy site, so their Meta is worth visiting.

Comment: @Josh you've been to and spent sufficient time in every single community to know that I suppose? I'd wager not. Like others have said, no matter how much you wish this is something you could generalise, it isn't.