# Grammatical error (inelegance at the very least) in a close reason

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, wording, grammar

I posted this on [meta.unix.se](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2731/22222) but it applies to the whole network so I'm reposting here. One of the canned messages for closing a question reads

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. **As it's currently written**, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

As *what* is currently written? There is no subject to which the *it's* refers. While it's true that there is not much room for misunderstanding, it is inelegant and, strictly speaking, ungrammatical. Could we please change that to something like

> <del>Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what **your post** is asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.</del>

Or, even better, as suggested in the comments:

> As your post is currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

I realize this is not that important but it bugs the pedant in me.

---

This question is similar but requests a slightly different modification:

[Change wording of "unclear what you're asking"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194744/203101)

Comment: I think discussion about this topic should be kept to the page you linked. This question, with a bit of rewording, could be posted as an answer there.

Comment: I think *As **your post** is currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.* also solves the problem but sounds slightly more natural than your suggestion (to me at least).

Comment: @MarkAmery fine by me, anything that makes what the _it_ is supposed to refer to explicit works for me.

Comment: As a native english speaker, I don't see a problem with it, but again, I'm a native english speaker.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker as am I, just a pedantic one.

Comment: Oh boy, I thought the whole time **as it's currently written** refers to the closing text itself, not to the questions itself. So **according to current guidelines stated here** or something like that :D